# Uploading Multiple Videos on server simultaneously

Tags: java, performance, spring, upload

We have one web application(With Spring, hibernate and MySQL as a Database) in which multiple users can store the heavy videos(pre-recorded or record from application itself) on server at same time.

In that scenario, server load would be definitely more there. We are assuming there would be **500-2000** users in the application.

So what strategy i should use to ***reduce the load from server*** and make the ***response time faster***.

1) **Storing the videos on our server**(With large Disk Space), and using the **ActiveMQ/RabbitMQ** mechanisms for File Upload and download in the Queues.

2) Storing the videos on some **third party server**(like YouTube,vimeo etc) that will upload all the videos on one central account. I had recently check this thing with you tube and vimeo but they require the end user login credentials for each upload. And i don;t want in my application that end-users to provide their credentials before each upload.

Is there any other way to reduce the work load and make the response time better for simultaneously upload on server, then please guide.

Thanks In Advance,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Multi servers can help.
On a single server:
If you use a single core processor - only ONE client will get served.
If you use a multi core processor and you are oppening a new thread for a new connection - only #ofCores clients will get served, and even that is not correct because your local memory might run out  before your os will save the data to your local hard disk (which has one bus), so serving 500-2000 clients leads you to a multi server solution.